# How to trigger sitecore personalization with Link.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, razor, sitecore, sitecore7

I am running into a wall trying to figure out if it's possible to trigger a query string personalization of a sitecore item using the following:

```
/~/link.aspx?_id=GUID
```

I've tried appending &_key=value but it doesn't trigger. IS this something that's possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom rule for query string, Sitecore doesn't have such a functionality out of box as far I know.

Please follow bellow link how to implement a similar functionality like you want:

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/custom-rules-and-conditions-for-sitecore-personalization/

Comment: I already have the content personalized with a query string, it's being able to trigger it using the /~link.aspx in the url. If i put the query string with a FQD it works. I'm looking for a code way to trigger it.